# org-mode clock-in in column view doesn't work on first clock-in?

Tags: org-mode

I like working in column view, as it shows me properties in columns.

I set clock-logging to go into the log drawer.

However, I've discovered that I can't clock in tasks unless a log-drawer already exists. It just says 'e' buffer is read only.

However, if I go out of column view, clock in once, the log-drawer is created and then go back into column view, then clocking in works.

Is this fix-able? If not, is there a way to always create a log-drawer whenever I mark a task as a 'TODO' task?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you can see the "todo"  keyword to todo(!)  which will cause org to log the creation of the todo keyword

Comment: Welcome to the Emacs StackExchange! Can you add some more detail to your answer, describing how exactly you make this change, and what exactly it does? I can tell what you mean, but it might not be clear to other users. In particular, this has the side-effect of logging when the task is set to a status of `TODO`, which may or may not be desired. See also [answer].